# Jackson YAML - serialize null as empty value

Tags: java, serialization, null, jackson, yaml

I am trying to customise the serialisation of strings to avoid `null` values in the `YAML` file.

The code I have so far:

```
YAMLFactory yamlFactory = new YAMLFactory();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(yamlFactory);
DefaultSerializerProvider sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
sp.setNullValueSerializer(new NullSerializer());
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializerProvider(sp);

Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("aString", "test");
data.put("aNullObject", null);
data.put("anEmptyString", "");

String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
System.out.println(output);
```

`NullSerializer`:

```
public class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString("");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
---
aNullObject: ""
aString: "test"
anEmptyString: ""
```

The problem is that `writeString` is writing an empty string, and I'm trying to have an empty value entirely.

Desired result:

```
---
aNullObject: 
aString: "test"
anEmptyString: ""
```

I tried to use `jgen.writeRaw("");` but I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation not supported by generator of type com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator._reportUnsupportedOperation(JsonGenerator.java:1967)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator.writeRaw(YAMLGenerator.java:590)
    at com.example.jackson.NullSerializer.serialize(NullSerializer.java:13)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.defaultSerializeNull(SerializerProvider.java:1127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:711)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1):

For me disabling of "MINIMIZE_QUOTES" feature didn't work, still, an empty string is written. The only solution I found was to override ObjectMapper and YamlGenerator and to allow YamlGenerator to write empty raw value. And also you have to provide a custom null serializer that writes this raw value.

```
class YamlObjectMapper(yamlFactory: YAMLFactory) : ObjectMapper(yamlFactory) {
init {
    val dS = DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl()
    dS.setNullValueSerializer(NullSerializer)
    setSerializerProvider(dS)
}}

class RawYAMLFactory : YAMLFactory() {

override fun _createGenerator(out: Writer?, ctxt: IOContext?): YAMLGenerator? {
    val feats = _yamlGeneratorFeatures
    return RawYamlGenerator(ctxt, _generatorFeatures, feats, _objectCodec, out, _version)
}}

private object NullSerializer : JsonSerializer<Any?>() {

override fun serialize(value: Any?, jgen: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider?) {
    jgen.writeRaw("")
}}

private class RawYamlGenerator(ctxt: IOContext?, jsonFeatures: Int, yamlFeatures: Int,
                           codec: ObjectCodec, out: Writer?, version: DumperOptions.Version?)
: YAMLGenerator(ctxt, jsonFeatures, yamlFeatures, codec, out, version) {

override fun writeRaw(c: String) {
    _writeContext.writeValue()
    _emit(_scalarEvent("", DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN))
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @Yuliia Liubchyk solution - I rewrote his code into Java.

Instance:

```
   var yamlObjectMapper = new YamlObjectMapper(new RawYamlFactory().
                enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES)).
                findAndRegisterModules();
```

```
class NullValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeRaw("");
    }
}
```

```
public class RawYamlFactory extends YAMLFactory {
    @Override
    protected YAMLGenerator _createGenerator(Writer out, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        var feats = _yamlGeneratorFeatures;
        return new RawYamlGenerator(ctxt, _generatorFeatures, feats, _objectCodec, out, _version);
    }
}
```

```
public class RawYamlGenerator extends YAMLGenerator {

    public RawYamlGenerator(IOContext ctxt, int jsonFeatures, int yamlFeatures,
                            ObjectCodec codec, Writer out, DumperOptions.Version version) throws IOException {
        super(ctxt, jsonFeatures, yamlFeatures, codec, out, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeRaw(String text) throws IOException {
        _writeContext.writeValue();
        _emit(_scalarEvent("", DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN));
    }
}
```

```
public class YamlObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public YamlObjectMapper(YAMLFactory jf) {
        super(jf);
        final DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl ds = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
        ds.setNullValueSerializer(new NullValueSerializer());
        setSerializerProvider(ds);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but using an enum (or object) and not a string directly you can implement a serializer and decide to add or remove the """ before to serialize the information.

For example

```
public class Data {
  private String aString;
  private MyData aNullObject;
  private String anEmptyString;
 ...
}

public class MyData {
  private String value;
  ....
}

public class MySerializer {
  @Override
    public void serialize(
            MyData data, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException {

        YAMLGenerator yamlGenerator = (YAMLGenerator) jgen;
        //DISABLE QUOTES
        yamlGenerator.enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES);
        yamlGenerator.writeString(data.getValue());
        //ENABLE QUOTES AGAIN
        yamlGenerator.disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES);
    }

}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(MyData.class, new MySerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

I hope to explain correctly...