# Jackson serialising Optional with null value for YAML

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, yaml, option-type

Currently I am using the [YAMLFactory](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformats-text/javadoc/yaml/2.11/) to configure the `ObjectMapper` to serialise and deserialise `Pojos <=> YAML`, however it writes `null` values in serialisation despite attempting the usual tricks in `Jackson`.

Annotating with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on the class level or the field level has no affect. I have also tried annotating classes with `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)` with no affect either. How do you achieve this when using the `YAMLFactory`?

I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163648/jackson-yaml-serialize-null-as-empty-value) but the use case does not appear to be the same. To be clear I am trying to omit the field altogether.

Edit: Here is an example (I am also using `Lombok`)

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class QueueProperties extends Properties {

    @JsonProperty("QueueName")
    private String queueName;

    @JsonProperty("RedrivePolicy")
    private RedrivePolicy redrivePolicy;

    public Optional<RedrivePolicy> getRedrivePolicy() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(redrivePolicy);
    }
}
```

when serialized:

```
Properties:
  QueueName: 471416d1-3643-4d5a-a033-65f22757dcaf-chargeback-paypal-ingestion-ingest_dispute
  RedrivePolicy: null
```

ObjectMapper configuration:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory().enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES));                                                          
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple example like in linked question which reproduces your problem? It would be much easier to understand your case and help with this problem.

Comment: Added the Pojo and how it serializes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getRedrivePolicy` getter method always returns `not-null` object, even so, `Optional` could reference to `null`. In this case, you should skip `empty` objects. `Optional` with `null` is considered as empty and we can use `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` for it. You can keep `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on class level and add `NON_EMPTY` only for given getter:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public Optional<Object> getRedrivePolicy() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(redrivePolicy);
}
```

Comment: I should be noted that `NON_EMPTY` worked only on the getter and not the class level.