# Scala Object Mapper write incorrect value

Tags: scala, jackson, yaml, objectmapper

I have an complex object which contains another object. I want to write it as yaml file.I am using scala with ObjectMapper . My final object looks like this

```
Configuration(Some(List(s3://etl/configuration/minioApp/23-08-2021/metrics.yaml)),Some(Map(inputDataFrame -> Input(None,Some(Kafka(List(uguyhi, ytvvt),Some(hgvgvugb),Some(ytfytvi),Some(yftug),None,None,None,Some( uyguytf)))))),None,Some(Output(None,Some(Kafka(null,Some(yrdryft),None)))),None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,Some(minioApp),None,None,None,None)
```

I want to write it to file. My main case class looks like this

```
case class  Configuration(@BeanProperty var metrics: Option[Seq[String]],
                      @BeanProperty  var inputs: Option[Map[String, Input]],
                      @BeanProperty  var variables: Option[Map[String, String]] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var output: Option[Output] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var outputs: Option[Map[String, Output]] = None,
                      @BeanProperty var cacheOnPreview: Option[Boolean] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var showQuery: Option[Boolean] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var streaming: Option[Streaming] = None,
                      @BeanProperty var periodic: Option[Periodic] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var logLevel: Option[String] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var showPreviewLines: Option[Int] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var explain: Option[Boolean] = None,
                      @BeanProperty var appName: Option[String] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var continueOnFailedStep: Option[Boolean] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var cacheCountOnOutput: Option[Boolean] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var ignoreDeequValidations: Option[Boolean] = None,
                      @BeanProperty  var failedDFLocationPrefix: Option[String] = None) extends Conf
```

and further input, output all class also have BeanProperty added. When I am trying to write this file using below snipplet.

```
val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory)
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("/Users/ayush.goyal/Downloads/servingWrapper/src/main/resources/input1.yaml"),jobYamls)
```

where jobYaml is my object as mentioned above. I am getting below file.

```
metrics:
  empty: false
  defined: true
inputs:
  empty: false
  defined: true
variables:
  empty: true
  defined: false
output:
  empty: false
  defined: true
outputs:
  empty: true
  defined: false
cacheOnPreview:
  empty: true
  defined: false
showQuery:
  empty: true
  defined: false
streaming:
  empty: true
  defined: false
periodic:
  empty: true
  defined: false
logLevel:
  empty: true
  defined: false
showPreviewLines:
  empty: true
  defined: false
explain:
  empty: true
  defined: false
appName:
  empty: false
  defined: true
continueOnFailedStep:
  empty: true
  defined: false
cacheCountOnOutput:
  empty: true
  defined: false
ignoreDeequValidations:
  empty: true
  defined: false
failedDFLocationPrefix:
  empty: true
  defined: false
```

Now this file has 2 issue

1. Values of object is not populated
2. I don't want to populated fields that have null value.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

As per the suggestion, I was abl to get below yaml

```
---
metrics:
- "s3://etl/configuration/minioApp/23-08-2021/metrics.yaml"
inputs:
  inputDataFrame:
    file: null
    kafka:
      servers:
      - "uguyhi"
      - "ytvvt"
      topic: "hgvgvugb"
      topicPattern: "ytfytvi"
      consumerGroup: "yftug"
      options: null
      schemaRegistryUrl: "yrftg"
      schemaSubject: null
      schemaId: " uyguytf"
output:
  file: null
  kafka:
    vservers: null
    checkpointLocation: "yrdryft"
    compressionType: null
streaming: null
appName: "minioApp"
```

As you can see in above yaml, Several fields have null value. I don't want to write them. How can I do that? I just don't want  those fiels to appear in Yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson doesn't know how to serialize `Option` as it's a Java library.

You can add the *jackson-scala-module* library and register the `DefaultScalaModule` on your `ObjectMapper` to let it know how to serialize common Scala types.

See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

Comment: I want able to get the values in Yaml file. but yaml still have some null values which I don't want. Updated question accordingly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is an option in Jackson to write null values or not, pretty sure the question has already been asked on SO. You should open another question though as per SO guidelines: one question per post otherwise it's a mess ;)

Comment: This one might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582778/jackson-serialising-optional-with-null-value-for-yaml